# System.NullReferenceException on remote Machine?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a web site with window form, I have an error of `System.NullReferenceException` only in remote page, if I try to open the page with visual studio, in debug mode, there is not problems! WHY!!?!?!?!

```
[NullReferenceException: Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.]
   GeCo.DetaglioMilitare.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\j972537\Documents\
Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GeCo\Admin\DettaglioMilitare.aspx.vb:45
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(
     Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

this is the code with the error:

```
 Dim militare As New ldap.utente
    militare = ldap.ldap_utente(matricola2)


    Label7.Text = militare.grado
    Label8.Text = militare.cognome
    Label9.Text = militare.nome
    Label10.Text = militare.codice_reparto
    Label11.Text = militare.intestazione_reparto
    Label12.Text = militare.email
```

this is the class module that I created:

```
Public Class ldap

Public Class utente

    Private _matricola As String = ""
    Public Property matricola() As String
        Get
            Return _matricola
        End Get
        Set(ByVal val As String)
            _matricola = val
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _grado As String = ""
    Public Property grado() As String
        Get
            Return _grado
        End Get
        Set(ByVal val As String)
            _grado = val
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _cognome As String = ""
    Public Property cognome() As String
        Get
            Return _cognome
        End Get
        Set(ByVal val As String)
            _cognome = val
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _nome As String = ""
    Public Property nome() As String
        Get
            Return _nome
        End Get
        Set(ByVal val As String)
            _nome = val
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _codice_reparto As String = ""
    Public Property codice_reparto() As String
        Get
            Return _codice_reparto
        End Get
        Set(ByVal val As String)
            _codice_reparto = val
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _intestazione_reparto As String = ""
    Public Property intestazione_reparto() As String
        Get
            Return _intestazione_reparto
        End Get
        Set(ByVal val As String)
            _intestazione_reparto = val
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _email As String = ""
    Public Property email() As String
        Get
            Return _email
        End Get
        Set(ByVal val As String)
            _email = val
        End Set
    End Property
End Class



' funzione per estrarre i dati relativi ad una matricola
Public Shared Function ldap_utente(matricola As String) As utente

    Dim directory As DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    Dim result As DirectoryServices.SearchResult

    Dim militare As utente = New utente

    Try
        directory = New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(cn=" & matricola & ")")
        result = directory.FindOne

        militare.matricola = matricola
        militare.grado = result.Properties("title")(0).ToString
        militare.cognome = result.Properties("sn")(0).ToString
        militare.nome = result.Properties("givenname")(0).ToString
        militare.codice_reparto = Left(result.Properties("physicaldeliveryofficename")(0).ToString, 5)
        Dim lenght_string As Integer = result.Properties("description")(0).ToString.Length
        militare.intestazione_reparto = Trim(Right(result.Properties("description")(0).ToString, lenght_string - 7))
        militare.email = result.Properties("mail")(0).ToString()

        Return militare

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return Nothing

    End Try

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you did not include information which line is `DettaglioMilitare.aspx.vb:45`, I can only diagnose what probably happened.

In you function `ldap_utente` when wxception happened you return `Nothing` which is same as `Null`. So to investigate what is wrong in your code you have two options:

1. Debug your code to see what exception you got
2. If debugging is not possible add logging to your code or throw this exception to see it in browser window\

I am almost sure that you have problem with connecting to Active Directory, because in 99% your page is installed as IIS user which doesn't have access to Active Directory. You can try to change application pool user to domain user.

Comment: But the connection with active directory has not problems, because when i connect with debug is ok, i can see every details of object. "If debugging is not possible add logging to your code or throw this exception to see it in browser window\" ehm i not undestand this step.  Thank you

Comment: Label7.Text = militare.grado <--happen here           as you write, the ldap.utente function return null, but why that return null with remote version, and with localhost version of debug return the object???

Comment: Because in localhost version you run application in your account context. On remote server it is context of IIS user, which does not have access to Active Directory